# How to enlarge presentation font size (for projector) in VS2005 for Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

In VS2008 it is Tools,Options,Environment,Fonts and Colors, Environment Font,then change default font from automatic to a real font and larger font size. Environment Font is not a setting in VS2005. Looks like older VS versions were Dialogs and Tool Windows (which is no longer in VS2005 or VS2008).

Answer (score 2):

You may be better off using [Zoomit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897434.aspx) for presentations.

Answer (score 1):

Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors -> Click on dropdown 'Show settings for" and select TextEditor. Then change the font size.

You can also try lowering your screen resolution, specially if you normally use a high resolution and you're also interested in your spectators seeing other mouse actions in the IDE (and not just the code)

Answer (score 1):

The text to enlarge is the text in Solution Explorer Window not in the code window (Text Editor). This can be done fine in VS2008 per my comment above from Tools, Options, but not in VS2005 that i am looking for. It could done in versions prior to VS2005. I will download and test ZoomIT thanks for that suggestion (i saw that used in 2008 PDC presentations)

my comment text above for Solution Explorer Window text (In VS2008 it is Tools,Options,Environment,Fonts and Colors, Environment Font,then change default forn from automatic to a real font and larger font size. Environment Font.)

Comment: "Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors -> Click on dropdown 'Show settings for" and select TextEditor" This will change the code window, not the solution explorer, not sure where you're looking at.

Answer (score 0):

Which text are you looking to enlarge?  Is it just source code?  If so, it's in:
Tools | Options | Environment | Fonts and Colors
Select 'Text Edtior' under 'show settings for', and change as needed.

Note that changing one of the text types (e.g. Plain Text) changes all others (Comment, Line Numbers, etc).  You might want to export your settings first using Tools | Options | Environment | Import and Export Settings, so that you can flip back and forth easily between presentation and not.

EDIT: load the settings on the command-line, to make it even easier to switch.  Use the command-line switch /ResetSettings with the filename, e.g.:
/ResetSettings c:\temp\mysettings.vssettings

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://visualstudiohacks.com/articles/general/optimize-visual-studio-for-presentations/), you can't change the size of the text in Solution Explorer, so I would second the recommendation for ZoomIt.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your posts!  I wanted to change the whole environment...not just the code.  I almost did it...  Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors->Text Editor I did prior to surfing.  Then Roy mentioned above to use Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors-> Environment Font.  That did 92%...  Than I changed ALL options I could to either Arial 11 or Tahoma 12.  EVERYTHING was changed except:  the controls when I drag them to the form.  Any further ideas?  It would sure be nice to see what I am creating!  I also want to set a standard font for all of my applications.  Where do I set it?  The default is either Windows San Serif 8 or Tahoma 8.

Thanks, guys!!  Hopefully I can return the favor and help others later.  < Steve >